# custom keras metric returns nan

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I want to further bucket the output classes into fewer buckets in a classification problem. 
I have 4 output classes (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3). But during training I also want to track the accuracy for 2 classes:

- treat 0 & 1 as class 0
- treat 2 & 3 as class 1

For that I created a new metric and compiled it with the model:

```
def new_classes_acc(y_true, y_pred):
  actual = tf.floor( y_true / 2 )
  predicted = tf.floor( y_pred / 2 )
  return K.categorical_crossentropy(actual, predicted)
```

Compiled it like so:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy', new_classes_acc])
```

I get `nan` as the accuracy value. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: When you used `tf.floor(y_true/2)`, all `class 1` will be converted to `class 0`, `class 2` and `class 3` will be converted to `class 1` and finally `class 2` will remain same. So you have created 3 classes `class 0,1,2` instead of 2.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Corrected my problem statement. Was a typo. Either way, I'm still unclear how to do this correctly in tf.keras

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are 4 classes and you have set `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss, then the labels are one-hot encoded and would be in shape `(n_samples, 4)`. Therefore, first you need to find the true and predicted classes using `argmax` function and then use `floor` function (further, you want to create a metric not a loss function; therefore you should not use `K.categorical_crossentropy`):

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

def custom_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    tr = tf.floor(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1) / 2)
    pr = tf.floor(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1) / 2)
    return K.cast(K.equal(tr, pr), K.floatx())
```

Now, let's test it. First we create a simple model and compile it:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax', input_shape=(2,)))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', custom_metric])
```

Then we create dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([1, 2]).reshape(1, 2)
```

and use our model to predict the labels for the given data:

```
print(model.predict(data))
# prints: [0.04662106, 0.8046941 , 0.07660434, 0.0720804 ]
```

So the second class has the highest probability and would be the predicted label. Now, considering the custom metric we defined, given either of `[1, 0, 0, 0]` or `[0, 1, 0, 0]` as true labels, the custom metric should gives us 1 (i.e. 100%). Let's confirm this:

```
true_labels = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0]).reshape(1,4)
print(model.evaluate(data, true_labels))    # gives: [3.0657029151916504, 0.0, 1.0]
```

The first element of the returned list corresponds to loss, the second one to `accuracy` and the third one to our custom metric. As you can see, the accuracy is zero (since the true class is class one but the predicted class is class two) and the custom metric is 1 as expected.

And the other case:

```
true_labels = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0]).reshape(1,4)
print(model.evaluate(data, true_labels))    # gives: [0.21729297935962677, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Here the accuracy is one (since both true and predicted classes are class two) and the custom metric is also one. You can further confirm this for the remaining two cases of `[0, 0, 1, 0]` and `[0, 0, 0, 1]` as true labels; both should return zero for the value of custom metric.

---

**Bonus:** what if the labels are sparse, i.e. 0, 1, 2 and 3? Then, you can use `keras.np_utils.to_categorical()` method to one-hot encode them and then use the custom metric defined above.

Comment: Great explanation. Cleared the concept on why we need `K.argmax` before processing. Just to learn more, what do you mean by sparse labels - how are they stored & retrieved and when are they used?

Comment: @Nitin By sparse labels I mean they are represented as integers like 1 or 2 or 3 etc. So the labels array have a shape of `(n_samples,)` , i.e. one integer label per sample. To train the model, you can use the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function if you don't want to one-hot encode the labels.